# Trouble receiving NMEA data from Serial Port Async Pro

Tags: delphi, serial-port, nmea

I am trying to get the NMEA data from GPS by using sample demo program. I am using Delphi with **Aysnc Pro - Version 5 (`TApdComPort`)** component. I used **`OnTriggerAvail`** event to capture the NMEA string. I found out that GPS unit is feeding different data count. Mostly it feeds one ASCII char at the time. I capture all the data using buffer string and then populate required NMEA sentences. It all works fine in my Demo program.

But the problem comes from when I integrated the demo code into my main application. I think my main program doesn't handle well on receiving single ASCII char. I noticed that while debugging, if the receiving data count (`Count` from `OnTriggerEvent`) has more than 100, it can be populated the data. But the receiving data count has 1 (this is more likely the case) will not be populated.

Please help me out here:

- Is there any better way to receive data from Serial Port when data
  comes in series of a single ASCII char continuously?
- Why my demo programs works perfectly but not on my main application?

Here is my Demo Code

```
procedure TFormMain.btnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Serial_init;
   try
      bufferString := '';
      CarrierOn := false;
      ApdComPort1.Open := True;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('COM port ', IntToStr(ApdComPort1.ComNumber), ' is open');
   except
      on e : EInOutError do
         Memo1.Lines.Add ('Error: ' + e.Message);
   end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.Serial_init;
begin
   ApdComPort1.ComNumber := 4;
   ApdComPort1.Baud := 4800;
   ApdComPort1.DataBits := 8;
   ApdComPort1.Parity := pNone;
   ApdComPort1.StopBits := 1;
end;

const
   NMEA_START = '$';
   NMEA_END_CF = #13;
   NMEA_END_LF = #10;
procedure TFormMain.ApdComPort1TriggerAvail(CP: TObject; Count: Word);
var
   sError : string;
   c: ansichar;
   i: integer;
   CarrierOn: Boolean;
begin
   for i := 1 to Count do
   begin
      c := ApdComPort1.GetChar;
      if c = NMEA_START then
         CarrierOn := True;
      if CarrierOn then // $ has been found collect the data
      begin
         if (c = NMEA_END_CF) then exit;
         if (c = NMEA_END_LF) then
         begin
            sError := '';
            if (PopulateData(bufferString, sError)) then
            begin
               ApdComPort1.FlushInBuffer;
               CarrierOn := false;
               bufferString := '';
               exit;
            end;
            CarrierOn := false;
            bufferString := '';
         end
         else
         begin
            bufferString := bufferString + c;
         end;
      end;
   end;
end;

function TFormMain.PopulateData(const Sentence: string; out ErrorMessage: string): boolean;
begin
   Result := SentenceDecoder('$GPGSV', Sentence);
   if Result then
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Data:' + Sentence); // Display received GSV data
end;

function TFormMain.SentenceDecoder(sentenceName, Sentence: string): boolean;
begin
   Result := Pos(sentenceName, sentence) = 1;
end;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried hooking up a `TAPDDataPacket` component and set the relevant properties for the NMEA data?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andy_D. Unfortunately, I am using **Async Pro version 5** which doesn't include `TApdDataPacket` Component. :(

Comment: Does your main program call `Application.ProcessMessages`?  If yes, that can wreak havoc on this style of event driven serial port code.

Comment: Is the hardware a Microsoft Surface Tablet?  I am finding that ApdComPort is not picking up the data when other programs do (GpsInfo.exe, HyperTerminal).